# Can a number register be used in a groff request?

Tags: units-of-measurement, groff

Can someone explain to me why embedding literal values (e.g., "1c") in the `.po` ("page offset") request works but referencing a number register does not?

```
.\" Set the dimensions of an A4 page.
.nr a4_width 21c
.nr a4_height 29.7c
.nr a4_margin_horizontal 1c
.nr a4_margin_vertical 1c
.nr a4_content (\n[a4_width] - (\n[a4_margin_horizontal] * 2))
.
.\" Page-offset and line-length
.po \n[a4_margin_horizontal]
.ll \n[a4_content]
.\" Uncomment the below two lines and everything works.
.\" .po 1c
.\" .ll 19c
.
.\" Start the document.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
.sp
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write the following line:

```
.nr a4_margin_horizontal 1c
```

the letter `c` is a scale indicator; thus the actual numeric value stored in the register will be about 28346.

When you write later:

```
.po \n[a4_margin_horizontal]
```

there is no scale indicator; thus the interpreter falls back on the *default scale indicator* which is `m` according to [line layout](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Line-Layout.html) (manual page).

If you want to make it work, add the `u` indicator after the `\n` request:

```
.po \n[a4_margin_horizontal]u
```

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how I bang my head against the wall for a full hour, then when I finally ask my question on StackOverflow, I figure it out.

From the online manual:

> gtroff (like many other programs) requires numeric parameters to specify
>   various measurements. Most numeric parameters9 may have a measurement unit
>   attached. These units are specified as a single character that immediately
>   follows the number or expression. Each of these units are understood, by
>   gtroff, to be a multiple of its basic unit. So, whenever a different
>   measurement unit is specified gtroff converts this into its basic units. This
>   basic unit, represented by a ‘u’, is a device dependent measurement, which is
>   quite small, ranging from 1/75th to 1/72000th of an inch. The values may be
>   given as fractional numbers; however, fractional basic units are always rounded
>   to integers.

My measure of `1c` (1 centimeter) was being converted to 28346 "basic units" (72,000 per inch), and the `.po` request was expected a default unit of measure.